# Quick conditional without return value Java

Tags: java, syntax

is there a way to make the "inverse" of this type of conditional?

For example, we have this conditional:

> number = (max) ? a : b;

Instead of returning a value, I want to execute an action, without returning anything, for example:

> (max) ? func1(a) :func2(a);

Is that possible? Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: This is something you can just try.

Comment: `if(max) func1(a); else func2(a);` can work, but it's not a good style in Java.  If you absolutely want it to work, just ignore the `return` values for the two functions

Comment: It doesn't work, since those functions returns `void`. At least eclipse show errors.

Comment: Just give it a return type of `boolean`, then return `true` (or `false`) at the end of both functions.  That way you can do this.  `boolean trashVar = (max) ? func1(a) : funct2(a);`